# Is there a feature like DirectoryIndex on Apache for Kitura?

Tags: apache, directoryindex, kitura

In apache I have the possibility to display the directory index instead of the index.html file. Like this:
[image]

Is there a similar feature in Kitura, that allows me to simply display the contents of the directory instead of having an index.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, Kitura does not currently support auto-display of the directory contents.